# How can I factor out clauses in a parameterized Expression?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

Hey all.  I'm trying to optimize a Linq to Entities call by statically caching and reusing a compiled query.  The query checks the same thing for a variable number of filter arguments, and the only way to compile query arguments like that is to explicitly use a number of arguments (rather than some Contains()-type logic, which in SQL can't be parameterized).

This works great and gives me a major performance boost.  The problem is that the code is UGLY.  I repeat the same chunk of code a number of times for each of the possible parameters.  I.e:

```
           Expression<Func<Entities, string, string, string, string, IQueryable<Instrument>>> query = 
(context, searchTerm0, searchTerm1, searchTerm2, searchTerm3) =>
                context.Instruments
                    .Where(
                        (searchTerm0 == null ||
                            instr.FullName.IndexOf(searchTerm0) > -1 ||
                            instr.ShortName.IndexOf(searchTerm0) > -1 ||
                            instr.Strategies.OrderBy(st => st.Level).Select(st => st.Name).Take(2).Any(strat => strat.IndexOf(searchTerm0) > -1))
                        &&
                        (searchTerm1 == null ||
                            instr.FullName.IndexOf(searchTerm1) > -1 ||
                            instr.ShortName.IndexOf(searchTerm1) > -1 ||
                            instr.Strategies.OrderBy(st => st.Level).Select(st => st.Name).Take(2).Any(strat => strat.IndexOf(searchTerm1) > -1))
                        &&
                        (searchTerm2 == null ||
                            instr.FullName.IndexOf(searchTerm2) > -1 ||
                            instr.ShortName.IndexOf(searchTerm2) > -1 ||
                            instr.Strategies.OrderBy(st => st.Level).Select(st => st.Name).Take(2).Any(strat => strat.IndexOf(searchTerm2) > -1))
                        &&
                        (searchTerm3 == null ||
                            instr.FullName.IndexOf(searchTerm3) > -1 ||
                            instr.ShortName.IndexOf(searchTerm3) > -1 ||
                            instr.Strategies.OrderBy(st => st.Level).Select(st => st.Name).Take(2).Any(strat => strat.IndexOf(searchTerm3) > -1))
                .Take(50);
```

I thought I'd be able to refactor this by dynamically creating the filter expressions, but it's seeming impossible.  I want to do something like this:

```
    var filterExpression = (instr, searchTerm) =>
        searchTerm == null ||
        instr.FullName.IndexOf(searchTerm) > -1 ||
        instr.ShortName.IndexOf(searchTerm) > -1 ||
        instr.Strategies.OrderBy(st => st.Level).Select(st => st.Name).Take(2).Any(strat => strat.IndexOf(searchTerm) > -1);

    Expression<Func<Entities, string, string, string, string, IQueryable<Instrument>>> query = (context, searchTerm0, searchTerm1, searchTerm2, searchTerm3) =>
        context.Instruments
            .Where(i => filterExpression(i, searchTerm0))
            .Where(i => filterExpression(i, searchTerm1))
            .Where(i => filterExpression(i, searchTerm2))
            .Where(i => filterExpression(i, searchTerm3))
        .Take(50);
```

But of course that won't compile because filterExpression is an expression and can't be called into like that (and it can't just be a Func because Linq to Entities won't recognize it as a translatable method).

I also can't capture the parameters in closures outside the expression, because if I reuse the compiled expression, the values from the last call will be hard-coded and re-used.  I.e., that's not a parameterized query.

Am I stuck writing out the whole thing for every term?  I'd like to support a maximum of 14.  Is it possible to factor out clauses that take parameters in this way?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). The docs are pretty good.

I've used it to support dozens of predicates and the resulting code is small when well-factored.

Comment: Not sure how Predicate Builder will help me.  What I want to do is to create an expression and compile it once, and then re-use it with different parameters. Unless I'm missing something, the Predicate Builder examples use filter values captured in the closure, i.e. they're not parameters to the Expression and will be re-used on subsequent uses of the compiled query.  Do I understand that right?

Comment: Ahhh... I see what you are looking for. You are correct, Predicate Builder would not do that for you. However, I don't think you can do the compiled approach in LINQ to EF. Essentially, all predicates are converted to T-SQL. The compiled query couldn't be converted by the LINQ to EF provider and you'd end up resorting to the Predicate Builder in the end anyways.

Comment: Yeah, the approach that I have at the top works - I can compile the compete expression and reuse it successfully with different parameters - but I end up having to write out the whole damn thing to support up to a dozen parameters.